# workspace not opening in oracle 11g application express but running fine in sql commnd line

Tags: sql, oracle

I have made a workspace in oracle 11g . It is running fine in command line interface of sql but it is not running in oracle 11g. I am unable to login in my workspace in oracle 11g express.

Comment: there may be problem with listener try to issue this command from Os `lsnrctl status`

Comment: it is not working